# Struggling to find correct data-bind structure for JSON payload

Tags: lightning-web-components, json, lwc-dom, databinding

I am having trouble `rendering multiple for:each loops` inside of each other and am pretty sure it is the structuring of how I have it. But I am not seeing where the issue is taking place. So when I take out the inner two templates, I am able to get the class number to show on the accordions as 1 and 2. But when I add the other two in it doesn't display anything. When I change the `1st inner template` to `class.classList.name`, I am able to see the two accordions with the correct labels. I am struggling to figure out the right structure to have things displayed properly with `data-binding`.

***The solution I am looking for is to have the number of accordions match the number of classes returned with each with the number of students and their extra activities with them listed under each name in their own accordion.*** I am currently able to get the right amount of accordions to render each time with the class number, but unable to get anything else to show. Some help would be appreciated as I am struggling to find the right structure.

P.S. sorry if the `JSON` is formatted weirdly, but I assure you the payload is fine and this is how it looks.

**HTML:**

```
<template for:each={outputResult.classes} for:item="class" for:index="index">
     <div key={class.classNumber}>
     <lightning-accordion>
          <lightning-accordion-section label={class.classNumber}>
               <template for:each={class.classList} for:item="student" for:index="index">
                    <div key={student.id}>
                         <lightning-button variant="base" label={student.name.first}></lighting-button>
                         <div>{student.phone.number}|{student.email}</div>
                    </div>
                    <template for:each={student.extraActivities} for:item="activity" for:index="index">
                         <lightning-accordion key={activity.id}>
                              <lightning-accordion-section label="Involved Activities">
                                   <div>{activity.name.activityName}</div>
                              </lightning-accordion-section>
                         <lightning-accordion>
                    </template>
               </template>
          </lightning-accordion-section>
     <lightning-accordion>
     </div>
</template>
```

**JSON PAYLOAD:**

```
    {
     classes: [
         {
         classNumber: 1, 
         classList: [
               {
                   name:{
                        first:tristan, 
                        last:berger
                   }, 
                   id:1, 
                   email: email@gmail.com,
                   phone:{
                        number:1112223456
                   }, 
                   extraActivites:[
                        activityId: 1, 
                        name: {
                             activityName: baking
                        }
                   ] 
               },
               {
                   name:{
                        first:eric, 
                        last:cartman
                   }, 
                   id:2, 
                   email: email2@gmail.com,
                   phone:{
                        number:1112223457
                   }, 
                   extraActivites:[
                        activityId: 2, 
                        name: {
                             activityName: running
                        }
                   ] 
               }
          ]
         },
         {
         classNumber: 2, 
         classList: [
               {
                   name:{
                        first:john, 
                        last:doe
                   }, 
                   id:3, 
                   email: email3@gmail.com,
                   phone:{
                        number:1112223477
                   }, 
                   extraActivites:[
                        activityId: 2, 
                        name: {
                             activityName: baking
                        }
                   ] 
               }
          ],
          }
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code had a number of problems. To get it all sorted out, I had to fix your JavaScript object structure and your template.

In your sample data, you tried to declare an array with an object property. I get that you think your data is correct, but I would double-check this.

```
   extraActivites:[
        activityId: 2, 
        name: {
             activityName: baking
        }
   ]
```

Should be:

```
  "extraActivites": [
    {
      "activityId": 2,
      "name": {
        "activityName": "baking"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Notice the missing `{}` pair.

You had `<lightning-accordion>` that should have been `</lightning-accordion>`, and you cannot use a reserved identifier name (`class`). You also misspelled `extraActivites` as `extraActivities` in your template (an extra `i` is in there), so the activities would not appear. [Here is the fixed version](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/hoRWx7YKda9VhJ0llXvY/src/app.html?p=stories).

---

```
{
  "classes": [
    {
      "classNumber": 1,
      "classList": [
        {
          "name": {
            "first": "tristan",
            "last": "berger"
          },
          "id": 1,
          "email": "email@gmail.com",
          "phone": {
            "number": "1112223456"
          },
          "extraActivites": [
            {
              "activityId": 1,
              "name": {
                "activityName": "baking"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": {
            "first": "eric",
            "last": "cartman"
          },
          "id": 2,
          "email": "email2@gmail.com",
          "phone": {
            "number": "1112223457"
          },
          "extraActivites": [
            {
              "activityId": 2,
              "name": {
                "activityName": "running"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "classNumber": 2,
      "classList": [
        {
          "name": {
            "first": "john",
            "last": "doe"
          },
          "id": 3,
          "email": "email3@gmail.com",
          "phone": {
            "number": "1112223477"
          },
          "extraActivites": [
            {
              "activityId": 2,
              "name": {
                "activityName": "baking"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

---

```
<template>
    <template for:each={outputResult.classes} for:item="classRecord">
        <div key={classRecord.classNumber}>
            <lightning-accordion>
                <lightning-accordion-section label={classRecord.classNumber}>
                    <template for:each={classRecord.classList} for:item="student">
                        <div key={student.id}>
                            <lightning-button variant="base" label={student.name.first}>
                            </lightning-button>
                            <div>{student.phone.number}|{student.email}</div>
                            <lightning-accordion for:each={student.extraActivites} for:item="activity" key={activity.id}>
                                <lightning-accordion-section label="Involved Activities">
                                    <div>{activity.name.activityName}</div>
                                </lightning-accordion-section>
                            </lightning-accordion>
                        </div>
                    </template>
                </lightning-accordion-section>
            </lightning-accordion>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

Comment: thank you for the help! The issue seemed to be the for:index as well as having my <div key={student.id}> closing tag not far enough out of scope. Sorry was copying over code from different computer.